# preg_replace/string_replace symbol - or * to space

Tags: php, jquery

My data:

```
-**abcd1234-*---
```

(something like that with - and * symbols in string)
and i want to data output:

```
abcd123
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: SO is not a free coding service, show us what you have tried.

Comment: Im trying convert/replace * and - symbol in my string to space and it didnt work. (my code: preg_replace('@(<\?[^>]*>)+@i', '', $part['0'];)

Comment: I tried also with `strpos` but it gets problem because * or - symbols they dont have fixed positon(anywhere in string).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few ways to do this. 
String replace, as mentioned by Ashish.

```
$input  = "-**abcd1234-*---";
$output = str_replace(array('-', '*'), '', $input);
echo $output;
```

If you have a large number of characters to strip though, maybe this would be a little easier.

```
$input  = "-**abcd1234-*---";
$remove = "-*";
$output = str_replace(str_split($remove), '', $input);
echo $output;
```

And of course, you can use regex.

```
$input  = "-**abcd1234-*---";
$output = preg_replace('/[*-]/', '', $input);
echo $output;
```